# Why is the discrete data in probability called probability "mass" function and continuous data related with probability "density" function?

Tags: probability

How exactly is mass referred to discrete and density to continuous type of data?

Comment: Interesting question. You may be interested in https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4220/35989 that answers it partially.

Comment: @Tim my question was why do we use the words "probability mass function" when the data is discrete and why do we use "probability density function" when the data is continuous? in what context is 'mass' and 'density' used here?